# Ubuntu (likely) reporting incorrect battery level

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery

A few days ago, Ubuntu (18.04 Bionic Beaver, kernel 4.15.7-041507-generic) started displaying an incorrect power level for my battery. How do I know? I don't, but my Dell XPS13 has a little button with five LEDs on the side that indicate power level. When I start using my laptop with a freshly charged battery, the Ubuntu-indicated charge drops from 100% to 77% in a matter of minutes, while all five LEDs remain on, meaning 80% and over. I believe the hardware indicator to be correct.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Hmm, what version of Ubuntu are you running? May as well note that in case this is a bug with Ubuntu or even just in general so we know.

Comment: good point @tommy61157, it's ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.7-041507-generic